# Flutter ListView builder never completes

Tags: flutter, dart

So im stuck on something that normally just works.

I have a firebase collection which contains a list of temmplates, i want to show these templates as a list view tile.

Stepping through the code reveals that the stream returns the items successfully , however when it reaches the itemCount property of the ListView it jumps out of the IF statement entirely and continues to display the loading indicator.

Debug console isnt showing any errors at all

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: firestoreDatabase.templatesStream(),
  initialData: new List<AppTemplate>(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      List<AppTemplate> templates = snapshot.data;
      ListView.builder(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(templates[index].title),
            subtitle: Text(
              templates[index].description == null ||
                templates[index].description == ""
              ? "N/A"
              : templates[index].description),
            leading: Icon(Icons.collections),
            trailing: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => {},
              child: Icon(Icons.delete),
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: templates.length,
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(child: Text('Error'));
    }
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: You need to `return ListView.builder`.

Comment: thanks, completely missed that.